# How to get .NET to look for assemblies in local folders first instead of GAC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, assemblies, gac

It is my understanding that .NET runtime will always look for referenced assemblies in GAC first and then in the local folders. Is there a setting in Web.Config that would invert this order?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.  It's not possible to achieve this.  If a DLL of equal version to the one referenced in your program exists in the GAC the CLR will **always** choose this one.  There is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: Is it something to do with security?

Comment: @codeulike, i believe it has more to do with servicing. I know less about the why and more about the ability to do so because I spent a lot of time trying to subvert this behavior before realizing it simply wasn't possible.

Comment: This is why the GAC is evil, in my book.

Answer (score 3):

More info. on work arounds in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267693/how-can-i-force-net-to-use-a-local-copy-of-an-assembly-thats-in-the-gac).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's something that will actually reverse the search order as such, but depending on your requirements you might want to look into [assembly binding redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(vs.71).aspx) which gives you quite a lot of control over which versions of assemblies are loaded.

Comment: This will change what version you bind.  However the version you end up choosing will still be subject to the GAC rules I mentioned.

Comment: Indeed, clarified the answer a little to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

JaredPar is right - the GAC will **always** get polled first for the assembly.  However, if you're like me, and want to have the DLL live in the GAC and still debug, you can add a build script to dump your .pdb file the same folder as the assembly in the GAC (it'll be in C:\windows\assembly\gac_msil\assembly.name_[public key token]).