# How can you use ASP.NET MVC build from source rather than the GAC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've installed the ASP.NET MVC locally, but I want to be able to use the code that is in the SVN repository on CodePlex rather than the released 1.0 version.  However if I remove the reference to the GAC assembly in my solution and add the reference to the locally built `System.Web.Mvc`, it will build fine, but at runtime it says:

> Parser Error Message: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'W:\source\projects\vinemedia\VineMedia.Site\bin\System.Web.Mvc.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of modifications in both web.config and ~/Views/web.config configuration files that need to be made for working with ASP.NET MVC source. You should read this - [Steve Sanderson’s blog - Using the ASP.NET MVC source code to debug your app](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/)

Comment: This post helped me getting MVC to run from the source.  I also had to remove the System.Web.MVC dll from the GAC.

Comment: Your app should work on ASP.NET MVC source without removing System.Web.MVC.dll from GAC. I have apps which are using MVC from GAC and MVC from source on the same machine and they works without any conflicts

Answer (score -1):

A `<bindingRedirect>` in your web.config file will likely solve this.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267693/how-can-i-force-net-to-use-a-local-copy-of-an-assembly-thats-in-the-gac) may help.

Comment: binding redirect for asp.net mvc needs to be GACed, and cannot use probing paths as explained in this post. Bad post.