# Oracle.DataAccess.client deployment not working

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, odac

I'm deploying an application that uses an oracle provider with `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in a machine that already has a specific version of ODAC `64-bit ODAC 11.2`.

But the application I want to deploy uses a more recent version of ODAC `64-bit ODAC 12.2c`. And in the root of that project I have the provider dll and its dependencies :

- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- OraOps12.dll
- oci.dll
- ociw32.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- orannzsbb12.dll
- oraocci12.dll
- oraociei12.dll

Once I deploy and run the application, I have the following error :

> Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I dont want to update the existing ODAC because it might be used by other applications.

I've checked different links as the following one: [Oracle.DataAccess.Client Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509331/oracle-dataaccess-client-dependencies/33527025#33527025) or this one : [Oracle.Dataaccess is in the GAC. Can I control the version I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374323/oracle-dataaccess-is-in-the-gac-can-i-control-the-version-i-use#) but it didn't work for me.

Also i though about using Managed drivers, but based on this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/intro004.htm), it doesn't support bulkcopy.

Is there a solution for this issue ? Or is there something I'm doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

My App.config file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"></remove>
            <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"></add>
        </DbProviderFactories>  
    </system.data>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.122.1.0" newVersion="4.122.1.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you need to use the Managed client?  I generally use the Unmanaged client for this reason - other people can install or update/modify the oracle installations which could cause yours to stop working in the future.  The only time I have found a reason to use the Managed driver is for Oracle Advanced Queue support.

Comment: Did you remove the policy DLLs from the GAC?

Comment: @DominicCotton the managed client can fix it indeed, but it does not support some operations we want to execute, bulkcopy for exemple.

Comment: @ChristianShay i tried that by adding `<publisherPolicy apply="no" />` but it doesn't work

Comment: @DominicCotton Have you gotten your statements reversed? The managed driver is the one that has no external dependencies: it's entirely written in managed .NET code.

Comment: @cheikh, try using gacutil /u to remove the policy dlls if they are in the GAC

Comment: Apologies yes I did reverse the terminology! :S

Answer (score 1):

In general it is possible to install more than one version of ODP.NET (`Oracle.DataAccess`) provider. However, due to unmanaged dependencies you would have to verify/modify the `%PATH%` environment variable each time before you launch an application which uses an Oracle driver. I don't think this would be a suitable solution.

I would see three possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

Remove the version attribute from reference. Then the application will load whatever ODP.NET version is installed on the machine.

In your `*.csproj`, resp. `*.vbproj` edit your reference to ODP.NET from

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86">
```

to this

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

I never developed a web-sevice, but I assume in `web.config` file it would be this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"></remove>
            <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" 
                 description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" 
                 type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess"></add>
        </DbProviderFactories>  
    </system.data>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Solution 2**

Install Oracle ODP.NET version 12.2 at target machine. Usually this is no problem unless other applications force a specific version (see [How to load specific version of assembly from GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818069/how-to-load-specific-version-of-assembly-from-gac)). Other applications which are using `Oracle.DataAccess` will be redirected automatically to version 12.2 - provided it is installed properly. When I did the last installation of Oracle 12.2 the ODP.NET was not installed in GAC, however you can configure it manually:

For 64-bit Version:

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x64\odp.net
set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

For 32-bit Version:

```
set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x86\odp.net
set OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

For ODP.NET Manged Driver (just for information):

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x64\odp.net
set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe

"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

**Solution 3**

Go to target machine and grab the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file (just the single DLL) and copy it to your development machine. Make a reference to this DLL. When you run/deploy your application then you will be automatically redirected to version 12.2, provided it is installed properly, see above.

Comment: The problem with this, it's that some applications need to target a specific version. If the server has an old Dlls installed, it will not work and the newly installed application requires more recent dlls to be work.

Comment: As @billybob says we want to target a specific version.

Comment: Why do you want to load a specific version?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the first solution didn't work for me, and in the solution 2, you suggested to have the latest version and all the application will use that one ! I don't want to be forced to do that every time i installed the application in a new machine. and the solution 3 suggested to use Managed dlls, but unfortunately we cannot do bulkcopy with that

Comment: @cheikhndiaye, sorry did a typo at solution 3