# Use older (2.x) and newer (3.x) version of Lucene.net.dll in a same .net project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, lucene.net

I want to do a comparison and performance benchmarking between the old token stream API and the newer one in the Lucene.net framework. I want to write a single console application for that and want to avoid writing two different applications, each bound to different version of lucene.

When I tried to add references of the older and newer version of Lucene.net dll in the .net application, VS 2010 complains that the reference has already been added. What is the solution? How can I refer to both the versions of the same dll in a same .net project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Making it more complicated might make actually it simpler. I would split it into 3 programs -- a console application for comparing the old and new APIs, and 2 no-user-I/O programs that feed into the console application, one bound to the 2.x Lucene and one bound to the 3.x Lucene. (It may even be that you can write the 2.x no-user-I/O program, then just derive the 3.x no-user-I/O program from it (depending on which version of 2.x you make the comparison against -- 2.9.x is pretty close to 3.0).)

*[edit...]*

You should also look at [Using different versions of the same assembly in the same folde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder)r, as it solves a similar problem.

Comment: I would not go that or some other route, unless there is a .net or visual studio limitation that multiple versions of same assemblies could not be used in the same application.