# Different EntityFramework versions in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, assemblies

I have an old Silverlight application that uses EF5 and can't be upgraded to EF6. I have another project that uses EF6 with a different context, but I get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm assuming this is because EF5 is already loaded (it's in the main project, don't ask me why) and it's still pointing to that `dll` instead of the EF6 one. How can I get this to work?

I added:

```
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="5.0.0.0" href="C:\Projects\project\2.1.1EF2\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll"/>
        <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="C:\Projects\project\2.1.1EF2\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

to my main web.config following lgos suggestion, but now I receive:

> {"[A]System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection. Type A originates from 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\project211ef\97babe28\e7ea3fa9\assembly\dl3\01275099\70646f08_d86ecf01\EntityFramework.dll'. Type B originates from 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Projects\project\2.1.1EF2\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll'."}

It looks like it's still trying to use EF5, despite it accessing the EF6 entity section.

I fixed this by adding binding redirects. In the main `web.config` I redirect to the new version then in a sub `web.config` redirect to the old version.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little more on the last sentence of your post? I solved the DLL issue, but I'm stuck on this [A] cannot be cast to [B] error.

Comment: @JakeWood This is all going off memory, but iirc I had my main web.config with the new version redirect and then in the folder where my silverlight project was I had another web.config with the other redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use two different versions of assembly in the same applications by defining assembly binding in config file. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder#2461746) should help you.