# How to reference a project that uses EF6 from project that uses EF5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I have a `WinForms` application that references a data model class library in the same solution. This class library uses `Entity Framework 5`. So far it works great.

I would also like to reference an external class library that uses `Entity Framework 6`, but at this point, as expected, I get the `System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0...`

From what I understood, I have two options (or maybe more):

> 1) Upgrade or downgrade one of the two, so they both use the same
>   version of EF (downgrade is probably not a good idea).
>
> 2) Make my solution to be able to support both versions (that's my preferred
>   option)

Now at this point I am getting stuck, because I am not sure how I can add references to EF5 and EF6, as both DLLs are called `EntityFramework.dll`.

I also saw these questions: [Different EntityFramework versions in same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895800/different-entityframework-versions-in-same-solution)

[Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' after downgrading EF 5.0.0.0 --> 4.3.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749175/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0)

But it's still not clear to me exactly how to do it. I can see that I need to add a dependent assembly in my app config.

Just to clarify, this is the project structure that I have:

```
- Main application
- Data model class library (uses EF5 and it is referenced by the Main application)
- External class library (uses EF6 and it is referenced by the Main application)
```

Is anybody able to help with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading multiple versions of the same assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451220/loading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly)

Comment: @JotaBe Yes, it is a possible duplicate, because I am not sure how to do it for the Entity Framework libraries.