# Referencing multiple versions of a dll in a project in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0

I have a project that has some dlls referring to Microsoft Unity 1.1 and my code is using Unity2.

I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder/2461746#2461746). However, I added the version 2.0 dll as reference in the project from visual studio and in the web.config file in the `<codebase ...>` tag's href, i pointed to the physical file locations correctly. During runtime, I am still getting the error as could not load assembly Unity 1.1.

Any idea on how to fix this issue is highly appreciated.

Config used is :

`<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <codeBase version="1.1.0.0" href="E:\Saravanan Doraiswamy\App\bin\v1.1\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll" />
                <codeBase version="2.0.414.0" href="E:\Saravanan Doraiswamy\App\bin\v2.1\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of redirection is not possible. Hence this post is closed.