# Using different versions of the same DLL in a project

Tags: c#, .net, dll

In my project I have to use different versions of `AWSSDK` dll's, in order to make this i took help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder/2461746#2461746.) . and added one of my dll in to a folder named `V-1` inside bin folder. Then made config changes like this

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="AWSSDK" publicKeyToken="CD2D24CD2BACE800" culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="1.4.8.2" href="V-1\AWSSDK.dll" />
            <codeBase version="2.3.40.0" href="AWSSDK.dll" />
        </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But I still gets the error like this

> Error 2   Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK, Version=1.4.8.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd2d24cd2bace800' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  E:\Live \Web.config    129

At this line in web-Config

```
 <add assembly="AWSSDK, Version=1.4.8.2,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CD2D24CD2BACE800" />
```

Can anyone please point-out what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Try altering the path... e.g. so it doesn't have a hyphen, i.e. make it V1

Comment: Are you aware that local paths in `href` are relative to the application directory? Perhaps you meant `bin\V-1\AWSSKDK.dll` etc. instead?

Comment: My next point was to say try a fully qualified path... e.g. href="file://c:/some_path/myassembly.dll"

Comment: @Luaan Not strictly true dood... "If the assembly is a private assembly, the codebase setting must be a path relative to the application's directory."

Comment: @Luaan tried changing path, same error

Comment: @PaulZahra tried it all not working

Comment: @Athul Make sure that both assemblies are strongly signed and the token is correct for both. i.e. if not strongly signed then versioning is ignored.

Comment: @PaulZahra both assemblies are strongly signed. But i can add token for only one here, so skipped second ones token. Can you say how it is done correctly?

Comment: Hmm you have a bit of a quandry then... strongly signed = publickeytoken... no public key token means versioning is ignored... hmm I suggest you first remove the second binding to ensure that everything is fine with the rest of your code... if so then add the 2nd binding back and try running https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to work out exactly whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please open **Solution Explorer** in visual studio
2. Open **References** under the project
3. Select **AWSSdk** reference and go to its properties.
4. Set **Specific Version = True**  and **Copy Local = False**
5. Make sure your output directory does not contain this dll in it.

Comment: Please check if NewtonSoft.Json.dll is not having different versions. I meant this dll must be of the same version. If not, then please do the same for this as well