# Nuget Requirement Conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

My MVC 5 project requires Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0 but I'm using an API library from Intuit that was built on Newtonsoft.Json verison 5.0.1 and doesn't work with the newer version.

Is there a way to run both versions on the same site?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I was trying to use Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.**8** which is what Intuit's API for QuickBooks (IPP) would not work with.

To resolved the issue, I installed Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.**4** and everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone my friend. Do you have Microsoft Blend installed? If yes, then that's the one you should blame to. 
Actually Blend installs the NewtonSoft.Json dll version 5.0.1 to GAC and unfortunately even if you have nuget installed Visual studio project prefers the version installed in GAC which is placed under Blend's installation directory under program files.

**Resolution**: Not recommended, but should do the needful. Just change the path of Installed blend.

e.g. Blend's installation path is:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Blend\....
```

Rename it to

```
 C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Blend_unused\....
```

This will give you a quick fix. The issue is already been reported to Microsoft connect site.

Comment: Nope, not using Blend.  It's an API library for QuickBooks Online.