# .Net Referencing library in two different versions

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, version

I am currently working on a project in C# which works with the Discord.NET and Telegram.Bot nuget packages. Both have a reference to Newtonsoft.Json libary but in different versions; Discord references to v8.0.3 and Telegram to v9. So if I run my application I get an exception that either the one or the others Version of Newtonsoft.Json was not found.

Is there any kind of solution or good practice on how to handle such an issue or delivering both libaries in a way .Net find them?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2461746/2842668