# Using different major versions of the same assembly in the same project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
Project A uses System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.3.0
Project A references Project B which uses System.Web.Mvc version 4.0
```

At compile time, version 4 of System.Web.Mvc is written to Project A's bin directory.  And as you would expect, I get `could not load System.Web.Mvc or one of its dependencies...` error.

There is a nearly [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder) question, but in this case the major versions of the DLLs are different, so a binding redirect will not work (the error literally says that `Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version`).

Upgrading one of the projects is out of the question for the time being.

So what can I do?

Comment: What if you overwrite `System.Web.Mvc` to be 5.2.3.0?

Comment: @mayu Oddly enough, that works fine for my immediate problem (`could not load System.Web.Mvc...` issue).  Didn't test what happens down the line with other functionality.