# Integrate unsigned package into signed project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to integrate a package in a .NET project that is included inside another project which requires me to sign every assemblies.

If I try to use said package I get the error below

'Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies A strongly-named assembly is required'

So I followed the recommandations found here:

[How I do a sign an assembly that has already been built into a dll specifically flute.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379954/how-i-do-a-sign-an-assembly-that-has-already-been-built-into-a-dll-specifically)

I tried replacing every dll by its signed equivalent but when I do that I get errors 'the type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced you must add a reference to assembly' as if the dlls were not recognized anymore even if 'using assembly;' does not return an error.

I also tried to download the package code, sign every dll there and compile my own package with the same result.

The package link is https://bitbucket.org/semiodesk/trinity/src/default/ if it can help.

I can't think of what to do next, my best guess is that something goes missing during the signing process of the dll, but I don't know what or even where to look.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First: I had something similar few years ago, I'm really sorry for you, it was a nightmare ^^. Second: Are the dll you are trying to sign are totally independant or have references between them? I'm really not sure but you may have some issues because you didn't change the number version between the unsigned and the signed version. Are you sure to use the signed versions? GAC and dll versions when getting messy can be really tricky...

Comment: I think you are correct with the dll hacing references between them, I am now finding every projects used in said dll and trying to sign everything in them. I will report here on progress, thanks.