# Use application with other version of dll without recompiling

Tags: c#, dll

I saw many threads about this problem but I couldnt find why my application doesnt work.
I want to use other version of Oracle.DataAccess library without recompling application.
I add to app.config lines:

```
   <assemblyBinding>
    <dependantAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0 - 9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.2.0.100" />
    </dependantAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```

If I good understand if I have version between 1.0.0.0 and 9.0.0.0 i force application to use version 10.2.0.100. But always when I change this versions application uses the same dll which was compiled.

My goal is just change dll in **local application directory** and force application to use this one

Comment: Is the other dll in the GAC ? If so then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267693/how-can-i-force-net-to-use-a-local-copy-of-an-assembly-thats-in-the-gac

Comment: You mis-spelled `<dependentAssembly>`, it can't work.